# I'm printing the return of a function but it doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, tuples

```
FILE_NAME = "file.txt"
FILE_CONTENT = "Hello, and welcome to ",FILE_NAME,"!"

def FILE_WRITER(file_,content):
    FILE_OPEN = open(file_,"r+")

    FILE_OPEN.truncate(0)
    FILE_OPEN.write(''.join(FILE_CONTENT))
    FILE_OPEN.close()
    return "Fully changed the content of",file_,"to",content,"!"

print(FILE_WRITER(FILE_NAME,FILE_CONTENT))
```

When I execute the code above, it returns :

```
('Fully changed the content of', 'file.txt', 'to', ('Hello, and welcome to ', 'file.txt', '!'), '!')
```

I understand that my variables aren't well named. I tried to search on Google to answer my problem but the only thing I found is that I'm maybe using "tuples" and that I needed to do the transform it to a string

Comment: Yes, you're using tuples and (presumably, you didn't say what output you actually wanted) need to transform it to a string. Given that you managed to find that out, why didn't you research how to do that? Also it's non-standard to use `SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE` for all your function and variable names.

Comment: Assuming you want a single string to be returned, use a [format string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) like `f'Fully changed the content of {file_} to {content}!'`

Comment: And you should probably change the `FILE_CONTENT` variable from a tuple to a string as well.

Comment: Lastly, please spend some time with a decent Python tutorial, for example the one from [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) (where you can also find very good reference material).

Answer (score 1):

```py
FILE_CONTENT = "Hello, and welcome to ",FILE_NAME,"!"
```

comma doesn't concatenate strings in python - it creates a tuple of three elements

try using

```py
FILE_CONTENT = f"Hello, and welcome to {FILE_NAME}!" 
...
return f"Fully changed the content of {file_} to {content}!"
```

instead

P.S. and definitely change your naming convention

Answer (score 0):

If you return more than 1 value from a function, it will be packed in a tuple.

For example:

```
>>> a=1,2,3
>>> print(a)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Your first sentence isn't really true, as your own example demonstrates - they're simply _not_ returning multiple values, they're returning one tuple. It's not to do with returning, as evidenced by the regular variable assignment you're using.

Answer (score 0):

transform this line

```
FILE_CONTENT = "Hello, and welcome to ",FILE_NAME,"!"
```

into this

```
FILE_CONTENT = "Hello, and welcome to "+FILE_NAME+"!"
```

Comment: better yet to use `f` strings

Comment: u r right, just beginners don't get it so i used simpler form

Comment: well, they gotta get it sometime

Answer (score 0):

You return a tuple of values, and `print` with a tuple is not the same as `print` with multiple arguments. The latter prints the `str` of the individual arguments separated by space (by default), whereas the former just prints the `str` of the tuple.

```
>>> file_ = "<file_>"
>>> content = "<content>"
>>> print("Fully changed the content of",file_,"to",content,"!")  # individual parameters
Fully changed the content of <file_> to <content> !
>>> print(("Fully changed the content of",file_,"to",content,"!"))  # a single tuple
('Fully changed the content of', '<file_>', 'to', '<content>', '!')
```

You have two options: Either, keep returning the tuple, but unpack it to individual arguments when passing it to `print`:

```
>>> res1 = "Fully changed the content of",file_,"to",content,"!"
>>> print(*res1)
Fully changed the content of <file_> to <content> !
```

Or, probably preferable, join the different parts to a string *before* returning it (since that's probably what the function is supposed to return, a string) and then just print it:

```
>>> res2 = f"Fully changed the content of {file_} to {content}!"
>>> print(res2)
Fully changed the content of <file_> to <content>!
```

Or, lastly, just `print` in the function itself, instead of returning the string.